# Azure FormRecognizer didn't work on Japan East?

Tags: azure, azure-form-recognizer

As title, I created a Form-Recognizer Service and deploy on **Japan East**. Then I try to get OCR results by API but it always return "status:NotStarted".

**Setp1: POST pdf and get `Operation-Location` URL**
Request URL:

```
[POST] https://{myservice}.cognitiveservices.azure.com/formrecognizer/v2.0-preview/custom/models/{modelId}/analyze
```

Responses:

```
[Header][Operation-Location] 

https://{myservice}.cognitiveservices.azure.com/formrecognizer/v2.0/custom/models/237e0a55-fcf1-469a-9a01-98c081b9b723/analyzeresults/3675fa59-a800-45a7-9335-097809f02ccc
```

**Setp2: Get analyze results**
Request URL:

```
[GET] {Operation-Location URL}
```

Responses:

```
{
    "status": "notStarted",
    "createdDateTime": "2021-02-08T07:31:38Z",
    "lastUpdatedDateTime": "2021-02-08T07:31:38Z"
}
```

Comment: Are you implying that it does work when you deploy it somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, Japan West is work! But I have to copy all of model from old form-recognizer service.......

Comment: In that case, it sounds like you should be lodging an Azure support ticket.